# How to do "static overloaded const" in C#?

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I'm creating a game in C#. Each level is made up of several tiles. Each tile is of a certain type e.g. grass floor, wooden wall, etc.

Ideally I would like to have one base class "Tile" and inherit from it to create classes for each type of tile. I would like to have the properties of the tile some kind of static/const/etc member of the sub-class since each type of tile is only ever going to have the same properties. I.e. I don't want 100 Tiles have a property which all have the same value, that seems rather inefficient.

The problem is you can't do that in C#. Are there any ways to achieve what I want?

My alternative idea was to separate it all into to trees, one with only the class "Tile" which represents an instance and another "TileType" from which I instanciate one object for each type and maybe access them through some kind of "TileTypeCollection". This feels strange though and I would rather do it in the first way.

Are there any general guidelines when dealing with a situation like this?

Comment: In OO programming the purpose of extending a base type is to modify or add behaviour, not to mutate properties/attributes. Your example requires only one Tile class - there may be different types of tiles sure, but these are only attributes of a Tile. Lets say your tile type has a virtual method *PlayerEntered()*, you could have a derived Tile class called *BlockingTile*, which would override the *PlayerEnetered()* and stop the player, or you could have a *BurningTile* class, which overrides *PlayerEntered()* and sets the player on fire..

Comment: The thing is that the tiles have certain properties like the name of their texture. This value will always ever have the same value for a certain type. Therefore it feels very bad to instantiate 100 tiles of the same type, creating 100 attributes containing the same string which will never change.

Comment: On a slightly tangential note, if you have 100 tiles that all have a property set to the constant string "grass", the compiler will have all references point to a single instance, rather than creating 100 String instances.  This means you only consume 4 (or 8) bytes per Tile for the reference, so it's not nearly as bad as you'd think.

Comment: That's precisely what the flyweight pattern is designed to alleviate, as Marino Simic suggests :) Does each and every tile really need a String property for the texture name? Is that what makes a tile unique? No... I think a Tile in this case needs only two properties, a position in the game world, and a tile type identifier... which is where the properties of a tile type (ie texture) would live.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for the FlyWeight design pattern:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern

> Flyweight is a software design
>   pattern. A flyweight is an object that
>   minimizes memory use by sharing as
>   much data as possible with other
>   similar objects; it is a way to use
>   objects in large numbers when a simple
>   repeated representation would use an
>   unacceptable amount of memory.

[image]

You have some C# samples here: http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternFlyweight.aspx#_self2

Comment: This feels like the best solution. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Also, do you possibly have any experience with the XNA framework? If so, would you say that the content importer uses this pattern?

Answer (score 2):

You can create a class structure as follows:

```
public abstract class Tile
{
  public abstract string BaseType;
}

public class Floor : Tile
{
  public override string BaseType
  {
    get
    {
       return "floor";
    }
  }
}

public class Grass : Tile
{
  public override string BaseType
  {
    get
    {
       return "grass";
    }
  }
}

public class Wooden : Tile
{
  public override string BaseType
  {
    get
    {
       return "wooden";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a **complete** misuse of polymorphism. The point of extending a type is to add/modify *behaviour*, not to provide different *data*.

Comment: @MattDavey: Thanks, for pointing that out. I actually wanted a comment on this solution, since my background is in C++ and recently when I wanted to achieve the same in C# I did it like this. Can you point me to the solution you like out of the ones here. So, I would know how to think of this in C#.

Comment: essentially in OO programming, an object is composed of two things - attributes (properties) and behaviour (methods). You can change the attributes of an object any time, but to add or change the behaviour requires polymorphism (not withstanding other patterns eg. Decorator). If you see my comment in the original question I gave example of when polymorphism may be necessary :)

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use a static field to back a property on your Tile base class?

```
public abstract class Tile
{
  private static string _commonProperty

  public static string CommonProperty
  {
    get { return _commonProperty; }
    set { _commonProperty = value; }
  }
}
```

Comment: Then the property should also be static.

Comment: Not necessarily - it can be useful to have a property that returns a shared value. (When you are implementing an interface, have a property with a default but overridable value, inheriting from a class or preparing that class for inheritance…)

Comment: @Jean Hominal: but this property will be returning a value shared by all children classes of this class, and from my understanding the question wants to return a different value of it for each child.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to have static properties on the child classes and a non static virtual accessor in the base class that when overriden returns the static values.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options which jump to mind depending on exact requirements.

IF there is a common property which differs in value for each type, then declare it in the base class, make it a readonly value and set it in the constructor of each type.

If you have properties which only exist on a specific type, then these should be declared in the sub-class and similarly read-only.